# Microsoft VS-Code and or Autohotkey questions Automatic tagging

Tags: windows-10, script, autohotkey, find-and-replace, visual-studio-code

How can I achieve this either using VS-Code of Autohotkey?

I am a Text books / Magazine books encoder and I'm using VS-Code (as my Notepad when typing). I am on a certain project which consists of tags for different book codes.

Sample TextFile:

"One of the greatest books in history of children's pilgrims is Dudafoss, but the favorite are Belkins stories".

The thing I want to find solution is like - everytime I type a certain text in VS-Code, there should be a corresponding tag to appear right beside it, ie:

1.)
when I type Dudafoss - (19084471) should appear right beside it.
when I type Belkins - (19042248) should appear right beside it.

So, the result should look like:

One of the greatest books in history of children's pilgrims is Dudafoss (19084471), but the favorite is Belkins (19042248) stories.

Search and Replace isn't a good solution, because there is a couple thousand tags (listed in my separate notepad)

Is it achievable in VS-Code, is there a function there that can do this? If not, how to write a simple Autohotkey code that can accomplished that?

Thanks, Marie

Additional Info: By the way, the Tagging file is already in Excel (Columns B and E).

Column B: Texts
Column E: Tags

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy Column B in a new text document (Texts.txt) on your desktop, 
Column E in another one (Tags.txt) 
and run this AHK code:

```
FileAppend, #Hotstring b0 *`n`n, %A_Desktop%\My Hotstrings.ahk

Loop, read, %A_Desktop%\Texts.txt
{
    FileAppend, ::%A_LoopReadLine%:: - (, %A_Desktop%\My Hotstrings.ahk
    FileReadLine, OutputVar, %A_Desktop&\Tags.txt, %A_Index%
    FileAppend, %OutputVar%)`n, %A_Desktop%\My Hotstrings.ahk
}
; Run, edit "%A_Desktop%\My Hotstrings.ahk"
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotstrings.htm

Comment: Great, but don't want it instantly or automatically. I want it to be executed or performed after pressing either an ENTER, or a SPACE or the TAB key. What do I need to add or change in the program?